# Data link to accdb file

Tags: sql, ms-access, ssis, oledb, linked-server

I want to make a data link(Connection Managers) from SQL server 2012, 64 bit to an accdb Microsoft access 2013 file.

I am using `Microsoft office 12.0 Access Database engine OLE DB Provider` and I have changed the `Run64BitRuntime` properties to `False`. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
 Test Connection Failed because of an initializing provider. Unrecognized database format 'C:\Access\Myfile.accdb'.
```

Also I have already  run these queries

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' ,
N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , 
N'DynamicParameters' , 1
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: can you post your connection string?

Comment: Data Source=c:\access\SQL_to_Access.accdb;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;